# View a caught exception in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a `try` `catch` structure in Android Studio. I place a breakpoint on my catch handler. How can I view the `Exception e` in Android Studio when my breakpoint is hit? I want to see the exact type and any properties of the exception.

Example:

```
try
{
  // do something that throws an exception here
}
catch(Exception e)
{   
  return 0;   // Breakpoint in this line is hit when an exception occurs.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see the exact type and any properties of the exception.

Watchers can you tell you every detail available

You will have a watchers tab on bottom of screen. simply type "e" in it and hit enter.

You can also hover your cursor over "e" and click + to view contents of the variable.

Just be sure that current breakpoint is at return 0

Comment: OK, thanks to this answer I was able to find my hidden "watches" tab. But when I try to add "e" I get

    e = Cannot find local variable 'e'

Comment: cuz your breakpoint might be at catch(Exception e). Make sure its inside the scope of catch

Answer (score 0):

In your `catch{}` block write out to the LogCat.  By doing this you won't have to be in "debug" mode to see the exception.  Your code will run much more quickly :)

```
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("Some Tag", e.getMessage(), e);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Exception` extends `Throwable`, you can use `printStackTrace()` to print the exception details to the standard error console (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())) - in Android's case, this is your LogCat.

```
try
{
  // do something that throws an exception here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  return 0;   // Breakpoint in this line is hit when an exception occurs.
}
```